# Links that clickable not in their place

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
    margin: unset;

}
#Sitetop {
    height: 51px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #003580;
}
#Siteundertop {
    border: solid 1px green;
    height: 59px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #003580
}
#Sitefinddeal{
    border: solid 1px green;
    height: 261px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
#Clean-and-Comfortable {
    border: solid 2px green;
    height: 520px;
    width : auto;}


    
                             /* Booking Site TOP Line code ! */
#Bookingbanner{
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    position: relative;
margin: 15px 320px 15px 320px;
}

#US-Flag {
  position: relative;
  left: 475px;
  bottom: 20px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}
.Currency {
    color: honeydew;
    position: relative;
    right:-410px ;
    bottom: 24px;
}
.List-your-property {
    position: relative;
    left: 480px;
    bottom: 23px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    background-color: #003580;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
.List-your-property:hover{
    background-color: rgb(0, 113, 194)
}
.register {  position: relative;
    left: 500px;
    bottom: 23px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.register:hover{
    color:  rgb(0, 113, 194);
}

.Sign-in {position: relative;
    left: 500px;
    bottom: 23px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.Sign-in:hover {
    color:  rgb(0, 113, 194);
} 
                             /* Booking site undertop code ! */

   ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    display:flex;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    
}

li{
    
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    left: 6.7cm;
    bottom: 0.5cm;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white
} 

a:visited{
    color: unset;}

   a{ text-decoration: none;
   } 

 a:hover{
     color: thistle;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/Booking.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arimo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Booking</title>
</head>
<body>
   
    <div class="search-icon" id="Sitetop">
        <img id="Bookingbanner" src="./img/Booking.com.png" alt="Booking.com">
        <a href="Language.html">
        <img id="US-Flag" src="./img/US Flag.png" alt="US Flag">
    </a>
        <a href="Currency.html">
        <span class="Currency">$</span>
    </a>
        <a href="https://join.booking.com/?lang=en-us&utm_source=topbar&utm_medium=frontend&amp;label=booking-name-he-ZjzRvp_RD_yeZ9lEt5OinQS267777970024:pl:ta:p1:p22,563,000:ac:ap:neg:fi:tikwd-65526620:lp1007967:li:dec:dm:ppccp=UmFuZG9tSVYkc2RlIyh9YcX_GyndjDE1z6LWmEwkC5A&amp;aid=376388">
        <button class="List-your-property" type="button">List your property</button>
    </a>
        <a href="https://account.booking.com/auth/oauth2?response_type=code&prompt=register&state=UpMEjJj93cBykWcEWKLGNSfXddyycziqAgVR6yJ1pGVxRruJDyIAux8dmEOibrOc3Lw4hMrO0sqlX4BZd6b48QUAH56X31O6ESqwnK-W0pukberLl2BgxoaR0SoGEn3q10fctcK5Re2Oc_erAZKYEiIENSjkT-6EoyBFVj0gIj78qzjzJu9JPoiKIbW3IXxjEq3bYrZ6PDd-sVwTKOFUIspm7fgD5eloas1-etR1Gq02nUxN4fFfbkzGPToPFwc4mrY_hCMMCtKRN3Uo8UlldzDygoJt-PDjWmAY-ug0h-axY5yF3wO6OlILAjcQOPLPxxHz7tSv2WNyCRrNTlkmXJVGtGjPBzrciOL7DC0y5IjavWkasUxF-lrNZ-RfCE6OqqNmcxnAb_uwGxhHxdrBSXBi_ZhbrWv67FlC80G9Fzk8Yf2cvSij04m2HsrZEHjIg-eHwvXVqBNFV2mlCdSjmRxCCtqe6Y2qDcElUR9KGTIdCMhnV_CDG7y71zwCe3Ci1HWwdruFadCVHDqGnb_whcK7Hnodm_fLIc65LUINvzFCAJKbvsOhriaDVrtXtOlGRW1g54IguIkc9RJzgqzUILISCb0uyYhPUqBQvVZmh43OdTth0scFT2qStzD7l0aqcqbeFl-5VIkOR87zcYM035oIxvIFeS6o5eEcOffv5HHNNqRfWOJpDfeYdMeH6uLRC7K5lpb5&lang=en-us&aid=376388&client_id=vO1Kblk7xX9tUn2cpZLS&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.booking.com%2Flogin.html%3Fop%3Doauth_return&dt=1594035541">
            <button class="register" type="button">Register</button>
     </a>
            <a href="https://account.booking.com/sign-in?op_token=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">
     <button class ="Sign-in" type="button">Sign In </button>
     </a>
                
    </div>
    <div id="Siteundertop">
        <ul>
            <a href="https://www.booking.com/index.html">
            <li>Stays</li>
        </a>
        <a href="https://booking.kayak.com/?sid=03bb72bf7455a06cce3ab22259e40400&aid=304142&label=gen173rf-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gDaGqIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQGIAgGYAiKoAgO4AqGfkfgFwAIB0gIkN2QyNDgzYTYtODJmMy00ZTM3LWI1MTUtOWI0MzJhMzczMjQ02AIF4AIB">
            <li>Flights</li>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.booking.com/cars/index.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaGqIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQPoAQGIAgGoAgO4Aty5kfgFwAIB0gIkMWJhZjRjODEtNGI4Yy00NzI0LTkwY2UtYjdlMGQ3NzNmNWFi2AIE4AIB;sid=03bb72bf7455a06cce3ab22259e40400">
            <li>Car Rentals</li>
        </a>
        <a href="https://experiences.booking.com/attractions/index.en-us.html?aid=304142;label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaGqIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQPoAQGIAgGoAgO4Aty5kfgFwAIB0gIkMWJhZjRjODEtNGI4Yy00NzI0LTkwY2UtYjdlMGQ3NzNmNWFi2AIE4AIB;source=booking_index-nav_bar_tours_and_activities&">
            <li>Attractions</li>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.booking.com/taxi/index.html?aid=304142;label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaGqIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQPoAQGIAgGoAgO4Aty5kfgFwAIB0gIkMWJhZjRjODEtNGI4Yy00NzI0LTkwY2UtYjdlMGQ3NzNmNWFi2AIE4AIB;sid=03bb72bf7455a06cce3ab22259e40400;tmpl=landing_pages%2Ftaxi;token=u96FAy6-ypGHaMOl6NbnbAFlSGfpghVkEWELUlGM5kkxNTk0MTIxNjk5&utm_campaign=cross_product_bar_2&utm_medium=intra&utm_source=booking.com&">
            <li>Airport Taxis</li>
        </a>


        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="Sitefinddeal"></div>
    <div id="Clean-and-Comfortable"></div>

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

I currently working on some homework I got from my school and I can't figure something out, I have needed to "recreate" Booking.com site, and I got 2 questions for you guys:

1. Why do I have links in the middle of nowhere? The "click" is in one place but the link is in the middle of the screen without any point.
2. Where I can find symbols that I can use like the real site? If you see the normal site, they have little airplane next to flight and I can't find a symbol like this and put it.

Thank you! The false links are under the left side of the "real links".

Comment: Please read [how to ask a homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). At the very least we need an example of the problem posted to your question here (show your code)

Answer (score 1):

The symbols that your refering are actualy fonts are are usually found under the name glyphicons. here is an example https://marcoceppi.github.io/bootstrap-glyphicons/

Comment: How do I use them, my friend?

Comment: It says how on the GitHub link: https://github.com/marcoceppi/bootstrap-glyphicons

Answer (score 0):

> *For the first question we need your code.* > **EDIT**

The reason you are getting this layout that does not seem to fit to graphical part consists of the use of `position: relative`, is it really necessary for achieve your objective?

If you try, for example, to use `position: absolute`, you will see that the page will change depending on the values that in your file are expressed by `cm` and `px`, and for that reason it could scare to see the page formatted in that way.

While, I can recommend you to remove `position` property if it's not strictly necessary for each **CSS** class, then you will see that no element will appear out of the page range, especially the links you requested for.

---

And for the second one, the symbols you're looking for can be obtained also with `FontAwesome`.
Check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_intro.asp

(Remember that without a license, you can only use simple icons and not all are availables)

---

I hope to have solved your issues with these explanations, to clarify some stuff comments are always accepted :)